# Designer 2010 Custom Action rights mask

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-actions

I have successfully added a custom action button to my ribbon, but I need to have authorization on it.

Not everyone should be able to click on it.

This is the button:

[image]

Any idea how I can add authorization to the button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way to add Authorization to a Custom Action button in SharePoint Designer is to add the required rights access in the "Rights mask:". For a list of available Rights Mask that you can use see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx.